# Error Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#documen__16C6400F5AFF46C6'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure its giving me an error

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#documen__16C6400F5AFF46C6'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.#documents'. The duplicate
> key value is (78812702)"

Following is the simplified version of the stored procedure. There is unique is check before adding data into table #documents but still i get this error. Its strange. Anyone faced such issues ? What could be cause of the issue.

```
drop table #documents
drop table #documentstest
begin
set  nocount on;

    BEGIN TRY  
    CREATE table #documents (VersionId int primary key, 
                                 MasterId int, 
                                 CadName varchar(160), 
                                 Revision varchar(10),
                                 Iteration int,
                                 LifecycleState varchar(20),
                                 ModifiedOn datetime,
                                 Lvl int)

    CREATE table #documentstest (Documentid int primary key, 
                                 MasterId int, 
                                 CadName varchar(160), 
                                 Revision varchar(10),
                                 Iteration int,
                                 LifecycleState varchar(20),
                                 ModifiedOn datetime,
                                 Lvl int)

    INSERT INTO #documents (VersionId, MasterId, CadName, Revision, Iteration, LifecycleState, ModifiedOn, Lvl)
    VALUES ('12345', '8945656', 'test.prt', 'A', 1, 'study', '2022-12-12', 1);

    INSERT INTO #documentstest (Documentid, MasterId, CadName, Revision, Iteration, LifecycleState, ModifiedOn, Lvl)
    VALUES ('123456', '435345', 'test1.prt', 'A', 1, 'study', '2022-12-12', 1);

    INSERT INTO #documentstest (Documentid, MasterId, CadName, Revision, Iteration, LifecycleState, ModifiedOn, Lvl)
    VALUES ('12345', '689789', 'test2.prt', 'A', 1, 'study', '2022-12-12', 1);

    DECLARE @lvl int
    SET @lvl=0

    declare @Rownum  int
    set @Rownum=1

    DECLARE @rowCount int

    DECLARE @publishError bit
    SET @publishError=0

    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' - LoopB - Level = ' + CAST(@lvl AS VARCHAR(25))

    --select distinct VersionId from #documents

    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' - try adding data' 

    BEGIN
        INSERT  #documents
        SELECT distinct Documentid, MasterId, CadName, Revision, Iteration, LifecycleState, ModifiedOn, lvl FROM #documentstest
        where @Rownum=1
        and Documentid not in (select distinct VersionId from #documents) -- added condiotion to check existing key
        SET @rowCount = 5
        PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' - done with adding' 
    END

    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' - executing after issue'
    INSERT INTO #documents (VersionId, MasterId, CadName, Revision, Iteration, LifecycleState, ModifiedOn, Lvl)
    VALUES ('1238', '689789', 'test2.prt', 'A', 1, 'study', '2022-12-12', 1);

    select * from #documents 
    select * from #documentstest

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
    THROW;
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' Caught Exception' 
    --  set @publishError=1
    --select * from #documents
    --select * from #documentstest
    --PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' - executing after issue'
    END CATCH

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 21) + ' Executing the END' + CAST(@publishError AS VARCHAR(25))
end
```

Wanted to resolve this issue but could not understand why such issue happens since there is a unique check before adding to it

Comment: This is definitely not mysql code, so removed mysql tag

Comment: Its working fine for me ! check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/LkebZRr3

Comment: Same, I can't reproduce the problem with the above SQL.

Comment: Please note that i could not reproduce the issue with above simplified stored procedure but almost same stored procedure showing the issue. Also sometime , it gives both primary key constraint and deadlock issue

Comment: Then take the time to produce a [mre], @Engineer . The reason for the error is clear; you are trying to `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) a row that breaks the primary key constraint.

Comment: As a side note, you apepar to be using `DISTINCT` in of places I wouldn't expect it to be, for example in `NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ...)` I'm not sure if you want the `SELECT DISTINCT` in your `INSERT INTO .. SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM` either.

Comment: I have seen some articles which says sometime deadlock can lead to primary key constraint issue. so wondering is that possible in this case ?

Comment: With local session temporary tables? No. Though deadlocks don't cause primary key constraint errors either.

Answer (score 0):

> it gives both primary key constraint and deadlock issue

This seems like a concurrency issue.
SERIALIZABLE (HOLDLOCK) will stop the race condition.
UPDLOCK will stop deadlocks.
Not good for throughput!

```
INSERT INTO #documents
SELECT Documentid, MasterId, CadName, Revision, Iteration, LifecycleState, ModifiedOn, lvl
FROM #documentstest T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM #documents D WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE D.VersionId = T.Documentid
);
```

Comment: Any links to article to understand your solution better ?